# How would I pick out a sentence by only looking for one word from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

The contents of the text file I'm reading into looks like

```
{'race': {'asian': 1.5386780205517425e-05,
          'indian': 1.2399948445818154e-05,
          'black': 2.54539722632785e-08,
          'white': 99.71753358840942,
          'middle eastern': 0.11004179250448942,
          'latino hispanic': 0.1723980880342424},
 'dominant_race': 'white', 'region': {'x': 183, 'y': 167, 'w': 286, 'h': 286}}
```

I want to be able to take the dominant race and store it in a variable. But do not know how to take it out and store it in a variable. also note as when the program runs the dominant race will change.

Comment: What have you tried?  How did that file get created?  That's not JSON format.  If you already have that data structure in a dictionary, it's easy to do the math on it.

Comment: Hey MC9010. Could you give us a snipped of the code you've tried so far? Having a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helps us help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is a dictionary. Dictionaries have `key` and `value` attributes. For example:

`my_dict = {'Indian': 2, 'Asian':4}`

In which `"Indian"` and `"Asian"` are the `keys` and `2` and `4` are the `values` for those keys.

In your question, your data has three keys: `race', 'dominant_race` and `region`. All you need to do to see the `keys` is the following command:

`my_dict.keys()`

Which will print:

`dict_keys(['race', 'dominant_race', 'region'])`

So, to get `dominant_race` you need to run the following:

`my_dict['dominant_race']`

which in your example will give you:

`'white'`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have got the data from the text file into a dict `data`:

---

This will store the the dominant race in `dom_race` and the value of that race in `dom_val`:

```
# max() for highest value
# data['race'].items() gets a (key, value) tuple from the dict (data)
# key=lambda x: x[1] tells max() to look at the value, rather than the key

dom_val, dom_race = max(data['race'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

```
>>> dom_val
99.71753358840942
>>> dom_race
'white'
```

---

Edit: I did not notice the `'dominant_race'` key lol, you can just use this:

```
dom_race = data['dominant_race']
dom_val = data['race'][dom_race]
```

Let me know is this is not how you want it stored